# ESP32: Sharing ADC between ULP (during deep sleep) and main program

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I have a program which reads a value from an ADC pin during the main program, the same ADC pin is used in a ULP program which runs in deep sleep to decide when to wake the main processor.  It is written using the arduino for esp32 framework.

The ULP program has a counter which lets me see how many times it runs between interrupts from another timer.  Oddly, the first run on the ULP works as expected, it runs the correct number of times and will wake up if I present an appropriate value on the ADC pin.  However, the next time the system sleeps, it only increments the counter once, it looks like the ULP program freezes.  I know that this is somehow related to the fact that I read from the ADC in the main program.  If I comment out the line in the main program which reads from the ADC then I get the expected behaviour and the ULP program runs correctly on every sleep cycle.  When I enable the one line in the main program that reads from the ADC, then the ULP only works for the first run.

Any suggestions?

In the setup, I load the ULP script and setup the ADC using:

```
adc1_config_channel_atten(ADC1_CHANNEL_6, ADC_ATTEN_DB_11);
adc1_config_width(ADC_WIDTH_BIT_12);
```

In the main program, I read from the ADC using:

```
adc1_get_raw(ADC1_CHANNEL_6)
```

Just before going into deep sleep, I setup the ULP period, enable the ADC for ULP and run the ULP program:

```
ulp_set_wakeup_period(0, 500000);
adc1_ulp_enable();
ulp_run((&ulp_entry - RTC_SLOW_MEM) / sizeof(uint32_t));
```

EDIT:  It also seems that there is some link with the timer interrupt.  If I disable timer interrupts the ULP functions every time correctly.  It is only after a wakeup caused by a sleep timer wakeup that the ULP stops working as expected.